# Mapping plugin settings to checkboxes

Tags: plugin-development

I'm struggling to figure out how to map an array of values in a plugins settings to a group of checkboxes:

```
protected function defineSettings()
{
    return array(
        'createGlobals' => array(
            AttributeType::Mixed, 'default' => array(
                "twitter" => true,
                "facebook" => true,
                "linkedIn" => true
                )
            )
        );
}
```

Here's one checkbox in my plugins template:

```
{{  forms.checkboxField({
  label: "<strong>Twitter</strong>"|t,
  name: '???',
  value: 'on',
  checked: settings.createGlobals.twitter
}) }}
```

As you can see, I've omitted the name value. Is there any way of mapping this name to the settings.createGlobals object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
{{  forms.checkboxField({
      label: "<strong>Twitter</strong>"|t,
      name: 'createGlobals[twitter]',
      value : 'on',
      checked: settings.createGlobals.twitter
}) }}
```

Comment: Arrgh! I thought it would be this but stupidly tried including quotes in the object property.